How to disable Multi-Camera Support in the ARCore session?
I'm using Pixel 8 Pro in auto-focus mode and when I get really close to the object it switches camera to macro. How can I disable that?
I tried:
setStereoCameraUsage(EnumSet.of(CameraConfig.StereoCameraUsage.DO_NOT_USE)) 

I'm expecting the camera to stay as wide angle one

To solve you're problem there are two options you can tried to change the first is add some additional changes in your code camera you can see my sample below.
private fun setupCamera() {
    try {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        
        // Create camera configuration
        val cameraConfig = CameraConfig.Builder()
            .apply {
                // Disable stereo/macro features
                setStereoCameraUsage(EnumSet.of(CameraConfig.StereoCameraUsage.DO_NOT_USE))
                // Disable auto macro mode
                setCaptureRequestOption(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                )
                // Prevent automatic switching
                setCaptureRequestOption(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EXTENDED_SCENE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EXTENDED_SCENE_MODE_DISABLED
                )
            }
            .build()

        // Apply configuration
        camera?.apply {
            setConfiguration(cameraConfig)
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera not initialized")

    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to configure camera: ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid camera configuration: ${e.message}")
    }
}

Don't forget to add permissions in your androidmanifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

And the second is change it to camerax which camerax can make you easy to handle various camera configurations. https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camerax

CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and CONTROL_EXTENDED_SCENE_MODE_DISABLED do not fix lens switching for me.
